# how does append(a +=", ") work in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was writing some javascript code and instead of writing `$("p").append(a +", ");` i mistyped it as `$("p").append(a +=", ");`.

After i ran the script the result was quite peculiar. I have created this [Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/0j8hmpwd/). Click on the button 3,4 times and the result would be something like this : `0, 0, , 0, , , 0, , , ,`.

As I am a beginner in javascript maybe i don't know some syntax which is causing this behaviour. Also i wasn't able to find any references to a similar problem anywhere. I want to understand how this is happening.

Comment: @fvu I think the confusion was due the fact that when we write `(a+",")` it actually prints the value of `a` concatenated with `,`.  Thanks for pointing it out though :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For every click the value of `a` changes.

`", "` is added every time the button is clicked. Since you set `a` to `0` only at the beginning it keeps on getting longer.

This is caused because of `+=`.

Writing `a += ", "` is equivalent of writing `a = a + ", "`.

Answer (score 1):

`a += ", "` is the same as `a = a + ", "`. So every time you click it, a is being modified to have another ", " at the end of it.

Answer (score 1):

`a += ", "` is the same as `a = a + ", "`

Basically what is happening is this. You start with the number 0. When you hit the button the first time, 0 becomes the string "0,", when you hit it a second time, you're saying "to the string 0, add the result of concatinating the string 0, and ," which gives us a string of 0,0,, ("0," + ("0," +",")), every time you click the button, the operation is repeated

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you hit the button, you are adding a comma and a space to the variable a.

+= is shorthand for a = a + ', '

Answer (score 0):

Your mistype is equivalent to

```
a = a + ", ";
$("p").append(a);
```

That is you are repeatedly concatenating `", "` to `a`.